# Run jQuery function stored in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The question is not only about jQuery, but JS in general.

I have a function, and depending on parameter's value I would like to do different "tasks" inside this function.

```
function show(animate) {
    if(animate) {
        $('.someElement1').slideDown();
        $('.someElement2').slideDown();
        // ...
        $('.someElementn').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.someElement1').show();
        $('.someElement2').show();
        // ...
        $('.someElementn').show();
    }
}
```

I don't want `if` statement, I would rather like do it like below:

```
function show(animate) {
    var animation = 'slideDown'; // $.fn.slideDown
    if(!animate) {
        animation = 'show'; // $.fn.show
    }
    // $('.someElement1'). [run function stored in animation var] ();
    // $('.someElement2'). [run function stored in animation var] ();
    // ...
    // $('.someElementn'). [run function stored in animation var] ();
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
var animation = "show";
$('#myElement')[animation]();
```

Comment: Oh really? Just remove dot in my snippet and it works. Lovely js;) TY @Anton